# Ubuntu with Windows fonts: Make font smoothing consistent including ligatures

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I recently followed part of a nice article on how to [Install Microsoft Windows Fonts In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-microsoft-windows-fonts-ubuntu-16-04/) and it seems to be generally working fine, I can see Windows fonts in Firefox and LibreOffice.

There's just a small annoyance with ligatures, such as the combination of the letters ti in "until", using the Calibri font:

[image: screenshot of text with a ligature]

Zooming in:

[image: zoomed detail with ligature]

As you can see, the ligature has a different smoothing/hinting as the rest of the text, making it stand out at small to medium sizes. Increasing the size of the font gradually, there comes a point at which the rest of the text also becomes "smooth" and there's no difference... how can I achieve that at small sizes?

Note: I don't mind whether the ligature becomes "not smooth" or the other text becomes "smooth", I just like it to be consistent.

Another detail, not sure it's relevant: I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Have you enabled font smoothing, per https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/enable-smooth-fonts-on-ubuntu-linux/ ? See also http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/fonts-conf.5.html for more configuration settings.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the informative links, I tried the suggestion to create `~/.fonts.conf` but it didn't make a difference unfortunately.